# Android - Unstable Bluetooth LE (GATT)

Tags: android, bluetooth, gatt

Now i write program for communication devices and telephone - protocol Bluetooth GATT (Android 4.3 HTC ONE). Faced with the problem of a stable connection to the phone. I created a service that connects required devices (as in the example from the official Google). Service creates an array of connections. When you first start, usually, only the first connected device, but after restarting software and Bluetooth, everything starts to work steadily. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more your newer Android, the more stable it works. My Android 4.4 was working very stable.